# Calculate standard deviation for multidimensional vector in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> targetInputs, targetOutputs;
std::ifstream inputData("inputData.txt");
std::ifstream outputData("outputData.txt");
if (!inputData || !outputData) {/*error*/}
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inputData, line))
{
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    targetInputs.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<float>(ss), std::istream_iterator<float>());
    targetOutputs.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<float>(ss), std::istream_iterator<float>());
}
inputData.close();
outputData.close();

std::vector<float> inputMean( targetInputs[0].size() );
std::vector<float> inputSTD( targetInputs[0].size() );
std::for_each(targetInputs.begin(), targetInputs.end(),
    [&](const std::vector<float>& row)
    {
        std::transform(row.begin(), row.end(), inputMean.begin(), inputMean.begin(),
            [](float d1, float d2) { return d1 + d2; });
    });
std::cout << "Column means: ";
std::transform(
    inputMean.begin(), inputMean.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "),
    [&targetInputs](float d) {return d / targetInputs.size(); });

std::for_each(targetInputs.begin(), targetInputs.end(),
    [&](const std::vector<float>& row)
    {
        std::transform(row.begin(), row.end(), inputSTD.begin(), inputSTD.begin(),
            [&inputMean](float d1, float d2) { return d1 + pow(d2-inputMean[row],2); });
    });
```

The targetInput vector was called from the .txt files that have three columns and more than 100 rows. I'm trying to get mean matrix and standard deviation matrix with three elements and I used same for_each and transform format to achieve both of them. In fact, it works fine with mean value but, I have no idea how to call each inputMean value for each column. Can we call vector array in lambda function?

Comment: I suggest to try to simplify this question, or minimize the code...

Comment: Please show some input data, and describe precisely what the issue is. Your current description is not entirely clear.

Comment: the inputfile can be simply numbers with a number of rows and 3 columns and outputfile is the same number of rows with inputfile with single column. 
can be 
//input file
{{1 2 3},{4 5 6},{7 8 9},{1 2 3}}
//output file
{{1},{2},{3},{4}}

Comment: @cigien Trying to get the input file average at each column and divide with the average so column 1 will be divided with inputMean[0] and column 2 will be divided with inputMean[1] and so on